# Batch File Removing File Extension

Tags: batch-file

So I've made a batch file to help me extract the video only from an MKV file using MKVToolNix and then re-encode the h264 file to an MP4 for video editing using mp4box. It works really well, this is how it looks:

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvextract.exe" --ui-language en tracks "%%a" 0:"%Sources%\h264\%%a.h264"
for %%a in (*.h264) do mp4box.exe -add "%%a:fps=23.976" "%Sources%\%%a.mp4"
```

Problem is, the first line would extract the file with <filename>.mkv.h264 then when I go to encode the file with mp4box to a MP4 file it comes out as <filename>.mkv.h264.mp4.

Is there a way to code it so it'll drop the first 2 extensions and leave only with the .MP4? Searched around and can't find my answer for something that is after the fact (all the ones I've found is for removing the last extension which doesn't help me).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `~n` modifier to extract the file name without the extension when specifying the name of the output file.

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvextract.exe" --ui-language en tracks "%%a" 0:"%Sources%\h264\%%~na.h264"

for %%a in (*.h264) do mp4box.exe -add "%%a:fps=23.976" "%Sources%\%%~na.mp4"
```